# How to run Pytorch model in normal non-parallel way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am going through [this script](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/86bc3e516dde92fee0ce00668a3714c03155dd44/imagenet/main.py), and there is a code block which takes 2 options into account, `DataParallel` and `DistributedDataParallel` here:

```
if not args.distributed:
    if args.arch.startswith('alexnet') or args.arch.startswith('vgg'):
        model.features = torch.nn.DataParallel(model.features)
        model.cuda()
    else:
        model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
else:
    model.cuda()
    model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model)
```

What if I don't want either of these options, and **I want to run it without even `DataParallel`**. How do I do it?

**How do I define my model so that it runs as a plain `nn` and not parallelizing anything?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DataParallel` is a wrapper object to parallelize the computation on multiple GPUs of the same machine, see [here](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html).
- `DistributedDataParallel` is also a wrapper object that lets you distribute the data on multiple devices, see [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.html).

If you don't want it, you can simply remove the wrapper and use the model as it is:

```
if not args.distributed:
    if args.arch.startswith('alexnet') or args.arch.startswith('vgg'):
        model.features = model.features
        model.cuda()
    else:
        model = model.cuda()
else:
    model.cuda()
    model = model
```

This is to keep code modification to a minimum. Of course, since parallelization is of no interest to you, you could drop this whole `if` statement to something along the lines of:

```
if args.arch.startswith('alexnet') or args.arch.startswith('vgg'):
    model.features = model.features
model = model.cuda()
```

Note that this code assumes you are running on the GPU.

Comment: Thank you for helping. This works.  + very important to add `.cuda()` to all the `Variable`s.

Comment: Just curious:  what does this do: model.features = model.features?

Answer (score 0):

`DataParallel` is a wrapper you can bypass it and get just the original module by doing this:

```
my_model = model.module.to(device)
```